# Rails 6, Webpacker is compiling javascript files in wrong order

Tags: javascript, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

/app/javascript/packs/application.js    contain this

```
require("main/jquery.min.js")
require("main/jquery-ui.min.js")
```

javascript build on console shows like this

```
[./app/javascript/main/jquery-ui.min.js] 341 KiB {application} [built]
[./app/javascript/main/jquery.min.js] 132 KiB {application} [built]
[./app/javascript/packs/application.js] 1.52 KiB {application} [built]
```

Browser console gives error

```
jquery-ui.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'jquery'
    at webpackMissingModule (jquery-ui.min.js:6)
```

This is happening because files are compiling in wrong order not the order i'm enter

do you know what's i'm doing wrong

Thanks

Comment: Don’t import minified downloads; i.e., remove main/jquery.min.js and main/jquery-ui.min.js. Add the packages to your project with yarn: `yarn add jquery jquery-ui`. In your application file, `import ‘jquery’` and `import ‘jquery-ui’`.